# TimeZoneInfo.Local vs TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've been working with the `DateTime` and `TimeZoneInfo` classes and I ran into an interesting result with the following code:

```
var dstStart = new DateTime(2013, 3, 10, 2, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Local);
var result = TimeZoneInfo.Local.IsDaylightSavingTime(dstStart);
```

The result of this is `False`. I actually would have thought it would be `True` (DST starts on March 10th at 2:00 AM)

Then I tried similar code using `FindSystemTimeZoneById` instead:

```
var myTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time");
var result = myTimeZone.IsDaylightSavingTime(dstStart);
```

The result of this is surprisingly `True`.

I then checked to see that these objects are both representing the same time zone:

```
myTimeZone.Id == TimeZoneInfo.Local.Id // returns True (Both are "Eastern Standard Time")
```

My question is: **why are these results different, and more importantly how can I make them the same?**

My computer is definitely in the `Eastern Standard Time` time zone

More information:

I resynced my computer's clock, and I ran a number of tests to compare the `TimeZoneInfo` object that was returned by each of the above methods. Here is my test program

```
var timeZoneFromLookup = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time");

var dstStart = new DateTime(2013, 3, 10, 2, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Local);

// -- The following return true --

Console.WriteLine("Equal? {0}", TimeZoneInfo.Local.Equals(timeZoneFromLookup));

Console.WriteLine("Has Same Rules? {0}", TimeZoneInfo.Local.HasSameRules(timeZoneFromLookup));

Console.WriteLine("Same Id? {0}", TimeZoneInfo.Local.Id == timeZoneFromLookup.Id);

Console.WriteLine("Same Base UTC Offset? {0}", TimeZoneInfo.Local.BaseUtcOffset == timeZoneFromLookup.BaseUtcOffset);

Console.WriteLine("Same Daylight Name? {0}", TimeZoneInfo.Local.DaylightName == timeZoneFromLookup.DaylightName);

Console.WriteLine("Same Display Name? {0}", TimeZoneInfo.Local.DisplayName == timeZoneFromLookup.DisplayName);

Console.WriteLine("Same Standard Name? {0}", TimeZoneInfo.Local.StandardName == timeZoneFromLookup.StandardName);

Console.WriteLine("Same Support For DST? {0}", 
    TimeZoneInfo.Local.SupportsDaylightSavingTime == timeZoneFromLookup.SupportsDaylightSavingTime
);

Console.WriteLine("Same result as to whether date/time is ambiguous? {0}", 
    timeZoneFromLookup.IsAmbiguousTime(dstStart) == TimeZoneInfo.Local.IsAmbiguousTime(dstStart)
);

// -- The following return false --


Console.WriteLine("Same utc offset result? {0}", 
    timeZoneFromLookup.GetUtcOffset(dstStart) == TimeZoneInfo.Local.GetUtcOffset(dstStart)

);
Console.WriteLine("Same Conversion to UTC? {0}", 
    TimeZoneInfo.Local.GetUtcOffset(dstStart) == timeZoneFromLookup.GetUtcOffset(dstStart)
);

Console.WriteLine("Same result as to whether date/time is invalid? {0}", 
    timeZoneFromLookup.IsInvalidTime(dstStart) == TimeZoneInfo.Local.IsInvalidTime(dstStart)
);

Console.WriteLine("Same result as to whether date/time is DST? {0}", 
    timeZoneFromLookup.IsDaylightSavingTime(dstStart) == TimeZoneInfo.Local.IsDaylightSavingTime(dstStart)
);
```

Comment: When DST starts, time is set forward, so does 2 a.m. exist? Maybe it goes from 1:59 a.m. directly to 3:00 a.m.? It's worse when DST ends. Have you read about `DateTime`'s deep dark secret, when DST ends (called "summer time" in the EU) (from [More fun with DateTime](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2012/05/02/more-fun-with-datetime.aspx))?

Comment: This is true, the interesting thing about "2:00 AM" is that `TimeZoneInfo.Local.IsInvalidTime(dstStart)` returns `true` (which makes sense) but `TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time").IsInvalidTime(dstStart)` returns `false`. No idea what the difference is.

Comment: But when you pick up a `DateTime` that doesn't even exist, in the "purged" hour, how can you expect a meaningful answer?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have control of the `DateTime`, it is being generated by an external source. I don't need it to be meaningful, I just need it to be consistent

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I did a little bit of reflecting and I believe the inconsistency stems from how `System.TimeZoneInfo+CachedData.GetCorrespondingKind(TimeZoneInfo timeZone)` returns `DateTimeKind.Local` only in the case where `timeZone == this.m_localTimeZone` (ie, when the argument was the same instance as the `TimeZoneInfo.Local` property is based on).

In the case where you pass this other `TimeZoneInfo` instance you got from `TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById` I expect that it returns `DateTimeKind.Unspecified`.

This will (probably among other things) affect `System.TimeZoneInfo.IsDaylightSavingTime(DateTime dateTime)` where, in the case where `dateTime.Kind` is local, it does a conversion between essentially `TimeZoneInfo.Local` and your `TimeZoneInfo` instance and bases the conversion on what `GetCorrespondingKind` says for the source and target timezones (the conversion returns the original datetime in the case where source and target are both local).

Comment: Thanks for the update, I'll look into this a bit myself. Based on this answer if I want IsDaylightSavingTime(dstStart) to return true in the server's time zone I would have to do `TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(TimeZoneInfo.Local.Id).IsDaylightSavingTime(dstStart);`

Answer (score 5):

The difference in behavior when using the non-Local `TimeZoneInfo` is defined in the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460642.aspx).

The reason the first result is `False` is because the DateTime object you have created is technically ambiguous.  There is no 2:00 am on March 10 2013 in the EST local time zone.

The doc states that the `IsDaylightSavingTime()` method is "affected by the relationship between the time zone represented by the TimeZoneInfo object and the Kind property of the dateTime parameter".  The table in the Remarks section provides a description of each of the possible combinations.

When specifying a time zone by explicitly calling `FindSystemTimeZoneById`, the "Local Kind" DateTime argument is first converted from Local to the specified time zone.  **During this step, the ambiguous time is resolved into a legitimate value.**

Try adding this to your test:

```
var dstStart = new DateTime(2013, 3, 10, 2, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Local);

dstStart = dstStart.ToUniversalTime();
dstStart = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(dstStart, TimeZoneInfo.Utc, myTimeZone);
```

The final value of `dstStart` becomes **'3/10/2013 3:00:00 AM'** (assuming your machine is still in EST).  The same kind of conversion is happening within `IsDaylightSavingTime()` on the local kind parameter, which illustrates why it returns `True`.

The real surprise here is that the `IsDaylightSavingTime()` method doesn't raise an `ArgumentException` in either case.  The documentation says that it will throw an exception when given an invalid `DateTime` parameter whose kind is `DateTimeKind.Local`, but clearly this does not happen.

#### **Edit:**

After looking through the source code and comments for the `TimeZoneInfo` class, I've come to the conclusion that the `IsDaylightSavingTime()` method is not meant to throw exceptions.  This is a mistake in the documentation.